# jQuery div down when clicked and up when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently I got this code:

```
$("#right").click(function() {
    $("#signin").stop().slideDown(300);
});
```

It drops down when clicked, but I want it to `slideUp()` when clicked on again. Thanks in advance.

I have another question, if I wanted to make it so pressing the escape button would make it slideup, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#right").click(function() {
    $("#signin").stop().slideToggle(300);
});
```

Using `slideToggle()` means that it toggles every time you click it.

Comment: Oh wow that's amazing, didn't know that existed. Thanks!

I have another question, if I wanted to make it so pressing the escape button would make it slideup, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Derek answered that in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

As for your new question about the escape key, it will be something like this:

> $(document).keyup(function(e){
>
> ```
> if(e.keyCode === 27)
>     $("#div").slideToggle();
> ```
>
> });